# how to reduce an adjective clause

Tags: adjectives, clauses

- He is an artist who makes sculptures

Reduced adjective clause:

- He is an artist making sculptures

Is there any rule to rephrase as it should be? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just say "**He is a sculptor**."?

> Sculptor - an artist who makes sculptures.  http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sculptor

Comment: That's not the term that I am looking for @centaurus :)

Comment: @afaithfullearner Sorry, that's all I could come up with to help you.

Comment: This doesn't really provide an answer to the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

The second sentence is not a proper reduction of the first sentence.
The sentences have two different meanings.

The first sentence describes what **type** of artist he is.
The second sentence describes what the artist is currently **doing.**